# Bash script not working with string variable, runs fine in directly in terminal

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I am relatively new to Bash. I wrote a script to generate montage of images using `montage` utility from imagemagick, by reading list of png files from a text file:

```
IFS=$'\n'
count=1
for line in `cat pngListGr4`;
do
   montage -tile 4x0 $line $(printf "%03d" $count).png
   ((count=count + 1))
  done
unset IFS
```

where pngListGr4 file looks like this:

```
01.png 02.png 03.png 04.png
05.png 06.png 07.png 08.png
...
```

Hence I was expecting to generate file 001.png and 002.png as the montage of files 1-4 and 5-8.
But instead I am getting error:

> montage-im6.q16: missing an image filename `001.png' @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1795.

However following code works fine in terminal:

```
$ string_="01.png 02.png 03.png 04.png"
$ montage -tile 4x0 $string_ $(printf "%03d" $count).png
```

Why my string substitution in my bash script giving such issues?

Comment: This might help: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: You are setting `IFS` to `\n` to try to read lines, but that means that `$string_` will no longer break on spaces. If you copy-paste your script into your terminal, or you copy-paste your terminal command into a script, you'll see that both behave the same way in both places

Comment: @thatotherguy I tried unsetting IFS before montage, and then resetting it after montage, indeed my script works after that. Can you please write ur comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting IFS to `\n` to try to read lines, but that means that `$string_`  will no longer break on spaces in your `montage` command. The better solution is to use a `while read` loop which can both get lines and split them up into fields:

```
count=1
while IFS= read -ra line
do
   montage -tile 4x0 "${line[@]}" "$(printf "%03d" "$count").png"
   ((count++))
done < pngListGr4
```